# Comparing a object with a test object

Tags: javascript, arrays, compare

How can I compare the object with the test object in Javascript. And if the Testobject sets the same value to true output this Object Item into a new Object.

```
    Obj1 = [{
        name: Hugo,
        itsTrustee: false,
        itsSchollar: true,
       },
       {
        name:Bugo,
        itsTrustee: true,
        itsSchollar: false,
}];
   testObj = {
           itsTrustee: true,
           itsSchollar: false,
}
```

I tried Reduce and map. But I can't get the right value 
Like that:

```
this.obj1.map((item) => {
    let newObj = Object.keys(item).reduce((acc, x) => {

    });
});
```

But since nothing works correctly, I cannot show an example function here

Answer (score 1):

first you can restructure a little like this

```
Obj1 = [{
            name: "Hugo",
            something: {
                itsTrustee: false,
                itsSchollar: true
            }
        },
        {
            name: "Hugo",
            something: {
                itsTrustee: false,
                itsSchollar: true
            }
        }
        ];
```

then you can try using find function here is an example

```
const data = [20, 18, 15, 10, 9];

let found = data.find(element => element < 12);

console.log(found);
```

for you it's going to be something like

```
let found = data.find(element =>  JSON.stringify(element.something) ==  JSON.stringify(testObj));
```

if found is null that's mean there's no object with your

wish it helped you